# Why cannot load golang/protobuf/proto

Tags: go

```
const (
    Address = ":50051"
)
func main() {
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", Address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("listen on: %s\n", Address)
}
```

when I run: `go run main.go`
I get this error:

```
build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/golang/protobuf/proto: module github.com/golang/protobuf/proto: Get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto/@v/list: dial tcp 216.58.200.241:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve] as it's not _complete_. I assume you're trying to use [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1850) or some framework? Please post your whole file, including the imports.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following steps:

1. `go get github.com/golang/protobuf`
2. `go run main.go`